# How to handle a SIGPIPE error inside the object that generated it?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, send

I have two applications, one server and other client, both written in C++ and Qt, but both of them also uses a C library that uses C socket methods to perform a socket communication between them (and this all in Linux).

When both of them are connected and I close the client, when the server tries to send a new message to it, it gets a SIGPIPE error and closes. I did some research on the web and in SO to see how could I create a handler for the SIGPIPE so instead of closing the application, I'ld tell the timers that constantly send the information to stop.

Now I did learn how to simply handle the signal: create a method that receives a int and use signal(SIGPIPE, myMethod) inside main() or global (note: learned that from SO and yes, I know that signal() is obsolete).

But the problem is that by doing this way I'm unable to stop the sending of information to the dead client, for the method that handles the signal needs to be either outside the class which sends the message or a static method, which don't have access to my server object.

To clarify, here is the current architecture:

//main.cpp

```
void signal_callback_handler(int signum)
{
    qDebug() << "Caught signal SIGPIPE" << signum << "; closing the application";

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setApplicationName("ConnEmulator");
    app.setApplicationVersion("1.0.0");
    app.setOrganizationName("Embrasul");
    app.setOrganizationDomain("http://www.embrasul.com.br");

    MainWidget window;
    window.show();

    /* Catch Signal Handler SIGPIPE */
    signal(SIGPIPE, signal_callback_handler);

    return app.exec();
}
```

//The MainWidget class (simplified)

```
MainWidget::MainWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWidget),
    timerSendData(new QTimer(this))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(timerSendData,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(slotSendData()));

    timerSendData->start();
    //...
}

void MainWidget::slotSendData()
{
    //Prepares data
    //...

    //Here the sending message is called with send()
    if (hal_socket_write_to_client(&socket_descriptor, (u_int8_t *)buff_write, myBufferSize) == -1)
        qDebug() << "Error writting to client";
}
```

//Socket library

```
int hal_socket_write_to_client(socket_t *obj, u_int8_t *buffer, int size)
{
    struct s_socket_private * const socket_obj = (struct s_socket_private *)obj;
    int retval = send(socket_obj->client_fd, buffer, size, 0);

    if (retval < 0)
        perror("write_to_client");

    return retval;
}
```

So how can I make my MainWidget object created inside `int main()` handle the signal so he may call `timerSendData->stop()`?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The question which it was marked as a duplicate of did not even refer to `SIGPIPE` or anything about signals; it was just about handling unrelated network error conditions.

Comment: It was about handling ECONNRESET, which is *what you get when you handle SIGPIPE*. Nothing 'unrelated' about it whatsoever. The answer to the one is the answer to the other.

Comment: @EJP: `ECONNRESET` is an error that can occur while reading, not while writing, and it has nothing to do with `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Rubbish. It can occur during both reading and writing, and it is exactly the same thing as SIGPIPE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`SIGPIPE` is ugly, but possible to deal with in a way that's fully encapsulated, thread-safe, and does not affect anything but the code making the write that might cause `SIGPIPE`. The general method is:

1. Block `SIGPIPE` with `pthread_sigmask` (or `sigprocmask`, but the latter is not guaranteed to be safe in multi-threaded programs) and save the original signal mask.
2. Perform the operation that might raise `SIGPIPE`.
3. Call `sigtimedwait` with a zero timeout to consume any pending `SIGPIPE` signal.
4. Restore the original signal mask (unblocking `SIGPIPE` if it was unblocked before).

Here's a try at some sample code using this method, in the form of a pure wrapper to `write` that avoids `SIGPIPE`:

```
ssize_t write_nosigpipe(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)
{
    sigset_t oldset, newset;
    ssize_t result;
    siginfo_t si;
    struct timespec ts = {0};

    sigemptyset(&newset);
    sigaddset(&newset, SIGPIPE);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newset, &oldset);

    result = write(fd, buf, len);

    while (sigtimedwait(&newset, &si, &ts) >= 0 || errno != EAGAIN);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_SETMASK, &oldset, 0);

    return result;
}
```

It's untested (not even compiled) and may need minor fixes, but hopefully gets the point across. Obviously for efficiency you'd want to do this on a larger granularity than single `write` calls (for example, you could block `SIGPIPE` for the duration of the whole library function until it returns to the outside caller).

An alternate design would be simply blocking `SIGPIPE` and never unblocking it, and documenting in the function's interface that it leaves `SIGPIPE` blocked (note: blocking is thread-local and does not affect other threads) and possibly leaves `SIGPIPE` pending (in the blocked state). Then the caller would be responsible for restoring it if necessary, so the rare caller that *wants* `SIGPIPE` could get it (but after your function finishes) by unblocking the signal while the majority of callers could happily leave it blocked. The blocking code works like in the above, with the `sigtimedwait`/unblocking part removed. This is similar to Maxim's answer except that the impact is thread-local and thus thread-safe.

Comment: And how do you report the failure to the application? Given that single handles should not have side effects?

Comment: @EJP: When `SIGPIPE` is blocked at the time it would be generated, the `write`/`send` returns an error with `errno` set to `EPIPE`. You then handle this the same way you would handle any other write error.

Comment: Few if any libraries do that when invoking `send`. Pedantically correct solution to a problem that does not exist.

Comment: What do they do then? Make a non-thread-safe call to `sigaction` or rely on the caller to have blocked or ignored `SIGPIPE`? Just because few libraries do something correctly is not an argument against doing so. Few libraries handle out-of-memory correctly and this makes the majority that don't junk that you can't use in a serious program, not valid.

Comment: BTW if the caller provides the socket fd, then unless the library has to guarantee consistency of some on-disk structure or similar, I think it's pretty reasonable for a library to "let `SIGPIPE` happen" unless the caller blocked/ignored it. But if opening and using the socket is internal to the library (part of the implementation, not the interface) it definitely needs to prevent `SIGPIPE` from crashing the program or else document it.

Comment: I can only think of one use case when `SIGPIPE` needs to terminate an application: for command line applications that are expected to be used with shell pipes. In all other cases `SIGPIPE` should be ignored, no code should ever raise this signal.

Comment: @R.. First of all, thanks for the reply (and for all others who helped in the interesting debate that was made). I just read the hole debate between you and the other two contributors and I became convinced you provided the best answer - not because of the implementation itself, but because of the theory behind it. I mean, I actually didn't understand your resolution in terms of "how do I implement this in a code". Could you please complete your answer with a implementation example (or providing a link for that)? Thanks!

Comment: @Momergil: I added some sample code and further elaborated on related possibilities for dealing with `SIGPIPE`.

Comment: Just read your answer again. This is an impractical exotic solution, not the best practice. The best practise is to ignore `SIGPIPE` for code with blocking writes like yours, or block `SIGPIPE` and handle it only while in `epoll_pwait`.

Comment: Besides that, reviewing your answer 10 years later, the syscalls became much more expensive because of the security mitigations of CPU vulnerabilities. Your solution proposes doing at least 4 syscalls instead of one 1 `write` syscall. More than that, `write` may not write the entire buffer in one syscall and must be called repeatedly until it returns `-1`, which your code is oblivious to and makes it 4 times more expensive then otherwise necessary. Did your solution age well in 10 years? Do you still think that your advise is beneficial or that it actually causes more problems than it solves?

Answer (score 4):

> Now I did learn how to simply handle the signal: create a method that receives a int and use signal(SIGPIPE, myMethod)

You just need to ignore `SIGPIPE`, no handler is needed:

```
// don't raise SIGPIPE when sending into broken TCP connections
::signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

> But the problem is that by doing this way I'm unable to stop the sending of information to the dead client, for the method that handles the signal needs to be either outside the class which sends the message or a static method, which don't have access to my server object.

When `SIGPIPE` is ignored writing into a broken TCP connection returns error code `EPIPE`, which the socket wrappers you use should handle like the connection has been closed. Ideally, the socket wrapper should pass `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag to `send`, so that `send` never raises `SIGPIPE`.

---

When writing into TCP connections in non-blocking or async I/O applications, it is quite common to write into a connection when the peer just disconnected but this event has not yet become known to the connection handler. The connection handler can be perfectly able to handle this condition resulting in error from `write`/`send` but `SIGPIPE` bypasses this error handling completely. Using a no-op signal handler for `SIGPIPE` makes that `write` syscall return, but now with `EINTR` error. How `EINTR` is handled and whether `write` syscall is restarted or not on `EINTR` depends on OS and how that signal handler was set up and that is outside of any connection handler scope and purview.

The best practice for modern applications is to:

1. Never expect or handle `SIGPIPE`. `SIGPIPE` must be explicitly ignored with `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN)` when the process starts.
2. Never expect or handle `EINTR`. OS signals must never propagate to connection handlers from the low level code invoking OS-specific event demultiplexing functions, such as `select`/`epoll_wait`. All OS-specific signals must be handled in that low level event demultiplexing code only and be blocked at all other times, which is precisely what `pselect`/[`epoll_pwait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) were invented for.
3. Connection handlers must handle `EPIPE` from  `write`/`send` just like `ECONNRESET`, `EOF` on `read`/`recv`, or any other unrecoverable connection errors - log the event and its details, close the offending fd/socket, and carry on.

---

`SIGPIPE` was invented with the sole purpose to terminate processes writing into Unix shell pipes earliest.

`SIGPIPE` is incompatible with network applications that use connection-oriented sockets and should be ignored in the first lines of `main` function. Never waste your precious life time on trying to handle it.

Comment: Since the signal disposition for `SIGPIPE` is global, this is not appropriate; another part of the program might want the signal to be generated and might have a signal handler.

Comment: @R. True. I have not seen libraries that raise `SIGPIPE`, but would avoid or patch them if I do.

Comment: I provided an alternate approach that avoids changing any global process state in my answer.

Comment: I think while R's suggestion handles library pathologies well, in 95% of cases this solution is how you fix things.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Maxim's solution is appropriate if the code doing the ignoring is the main program and it knows it wants to ignore `SIGPIPE` all the time, but it's not code that you can safely put in a library. My approach works in either.

Comment: That's a good point, but the question is clearly about application development.

Comment: Also `MSG_NOSIGNAL` is the best way, but it's not always an option, e.g. if you can't use `send` but have to use `write`. Also, prior to POSIX 2008, it was not a mandatory feature, so some implementations that aren't up to date with POSIX 2008 (maybe Mac OSX?) don't necessarily support it.

Comment: @R. Ignoring SIG_PIPE is how 99% of programs do it. Stop complaining that someone provided a different answer from yours.

Comment: @EJP: I'm not complaining. I'm providing useful information about the pros and cons of different options. SO questions and answers are supposed to be useful in the future, not just for the OP, so expanding on them is part of providing a useful resource. As you can see I agree with Maxim that `MSG_NOSIGNAL` is the best way when it's possible.

Comment: Coming back 10 years later to add one detail: One bad thing about ignoring `SIGPIPE` with `SIG_IGN` is that the disposition of `SIG_IGN` is inherited by all child processes, which you might not want it ignored in. There's a really simple workaround for this: instead of setting it to `SIG_IGN`, set it to an empty handler function that does nothing but return, using `sigaction` with the `SA_RESTART` flag. This will behave nearly identical to ignoring the signal, but won't be inherited. (Also, only do this if the original disposition wasn't `SIG_IGN`; if it was, just leave it as expected.)

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE That's an interesting idea. When handling `SIGPIPE` with a signal handler, does that not change the return code of `send` from  `EPIPE` to `EINTR`? Is not `EINTR` handled differently by `libc`, in that it re-invokes the syscall on `EINTR` unlike returning `EPIPE`? I may be totally wrong here.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE When forking child processes you must also take care of signal mask, which is preserved across `fork` and `exec`, and file descriptors some of which shouldn't be inherited. A multi-threaded process can only `fork` to immediately `exec`, otherwise it may find some mutexes locked (mutex in `malloc`, for example) and deadlock forever.  In other words, ignored `SIGPIPE` is the least of the problems arising from forking. If you do `fork` and expect it to be robust, you must handle these other things explicitly, and reset the signal disposition while you're at it.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: It only causes `EINTR` if you don't use `SA_RESTART`. `EINTR` should generally be Considered Harmful and does not happen (except in `select`) unless you intentionally install interrupting signal handlers by omitting `SA_RESTART` or by using the legacy `signal` function instead of `sigaction` on a system where the `signal` function gives interrupting-mode.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Regarding child processes, the case you care about involves either `fork`+`exec` or `posix_spawn` (the modern way to do it). Forking without exec indeed is problematic but in any case, that's when you'd generally be fine with signal disposition remaining changed, vs executing some other program that doesn't expect a signal to be ignored unless the user explicitly wanted to run it that way. Note that signal masks, unlike dispositions, are thread-local, so methods that just alter and restore the mask don't leak unwanted state change to children.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Well, the use-case I care about is precisely forking Python child processes in the middle of Python functions by replacing `map` with my own `map_fork` and no other code changes. Couldn't care less about `posix_spawn`. I demand `fork` because I need all this global and local function state in the child processes as is. And I want my signal handler dispositions and masks to be inherited by the child processes.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE `fork` requires good understanding of what it does. One doesn't invoke `fork` casually and find it broken by some signal handler, file descriptor, shared memory mapping, signal mask, file lock, CPU affinity, controlling terminal or something else. Your comment about `fork` and signal handler disposition makes little sense from this perspective.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Each thread has its own signal mask.  `pthread_create` and `fork` clone the signal  mask of the invoking thread. Normally, you set the signal mask once for the the entire process and may unblock some signals while in `epoll_pwait` or dedicate a thread to signal processing which unblocks some signals. After that is done you forget about signals and the signal mask. That's the best practice.